# ATG 11 installation error : Invalid Weblogic home directory specified

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, atg, oracle-commerce

I tried to install ATG 11 but I get this error : Invalid Weblogic home directory specified

https://imagebin.ca/v/2kGp5sofKytQ

How can I fix this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Csaba

ENV: WIN7, ATG11.0, WL 12.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Supported Platforms Matrix for ATG 11.0 and WebLogic (an unofficial version is available [here](http://world-of-atg.blogspot.co.za/2014/03/supported-environments-matrix-for.html)). You will find that Weblogic 12.2.1 is not supported for ATG 11.0 but Weblogic 12.1.2 is.

In the event that 12.2.1 was a typing mistake, check the read permissions on your `WEBLOGIC_HOME` folder. I've seen on numerous issues where the `wlserver` folder was not readable by the profile trying to install ATG on Windows 7.0.

Comment: Thanks man, im going to check them soon, Im a bit tired because of much tries. I also thought that its a permission problem, because weblogic warn me to be installed as administrator, but could not find the clue. And thanks for the support matrix as well, earlier i also want to find such summary.

Comment: @user647314 I notice that you are using java 1.8 which is also not supported by Oracle Commerce version 11.0.  You need to use version 1.7.

Comment: Thanks @user647314, since then I use jboss, thanks to radimpe i used the compatibility table as well. And I find another useful link which make much easier to try the atg with eclipse : http://www.asknsay.com/creating-new-atg-project-in-eclipse.html

Comment: I set full control for all user type to Weblogic home and its sub directories, without  success, but I think you are right, later i will come back to this problem again. I need some success till then :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the Same issue while installing ATG 11.2 with weblogic 12.2.1 .
Root cause was version compatibility.
After installing lower wersion of weblogic 12.1 , it worked.